# Page numbering issue on part and chapter pages

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

I want to have my pages on the top right corner of all of my pages. However, for every `\part` and `\chapter` the page number is on the bottom middle.

My code (the numbering part) is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\part{aaaaaaaa}
\chapter{bbbbbb}
\chapter{ccccc}
\section{ddddd}
\end{document}
```

There is way more code and of course lots of stuff written everywhere. On this example, the page number is on the bottom middle for the page with `\part{aaaaaaaa}`, `\chapter{bbbbbb}`, `\chapter{ccccc}`, on the top right for the rest of the document and I would like to have it on the top right corner for every pages.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First pages of chapters use the `plain` page style. To also move the page number on these pages, you can redefine the pagestyle using `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\fancyfoot{}\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}}`. (See also "10  Redefining page style plain" in the `fancyhdr` package manual.)  To additionally get rid of the warning `Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):` I have added `\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}`to your example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document}
\part{aaaaaaaa}
\chapter{bbbbbb}
\chapter{ccccc}
\section{ddddd}

\end{document}
```

Sincoe you are using `twoside` you might also be interested to use `\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}` instead of `\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly.

What does \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage} does?

Comment: R and L stand for right and left, while O and E stand for odd and even. RO and LE ensure that your page numbers will always be at the outer margin if you print your document double sided.